# How to change the code according to compatibility of Angular 10?

Tags: angular, datetime

In the component.ts file I have :-

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment_ from 'moment';

let moment=moment_;
type Moment=moment_.Moment;

export class DateTimeComponent implements OnInit {
    private _ngModel: Moment= moment();

    @Input()
    datePlaceHolder: string = "Date";

    @Input()
    timePlaceHolder: string = "Time";

    @Input()
    timeFormat:number=24;

    @Input()
    minutesGap:number=1;

    timePart: string | Moment="";

    datePart:Moment;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    @Input()
    get ngModel() {
        return this._ngModel
    }

    @Output()
    ngModelChange = new EventEmitter <Moment>();

    set ngModel(date: Moment) {
        let m=date.minutes()+this.minutesGap-1;
        date.minutes(m  - (m % this.minutesGap));
        this.timePart = date;
        this.datePart=date;
        this._ngModel = date;
        this.ngModelChange.emit(date);
    }
    timePartChange(ev:any) {
        let d = moment(this._ngModel);
        let m=moment(ev,"LT");
        d.hours(m.hours()).minutes(m.minutes());
        this.ngModel=d;
    }

    datePartChange(ev:Moment) {
        let d = this._ngModel;
        ev.hours(d.hours()).minutes(d.minutes());
        this.ngModel=ev;
    }
}
```

In the .html :-

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{datePlaceHolder}}" [matDatepicker]="picker" [(ngModel)]="datePart" (ngModelChange)="datePartChange($event)"/>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field><br/>

<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="{{timePlaceHolder}}" [format]="timeFormat"  readonly [(ngModel)]="timePart" (ngModelChange)="timePartChange($event)" [ngxTimepicker]="timepicker"/>
    <ngx-material-timepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="timepicker"></ngx-material-timepicker-toggle>
    <ngx-material-timepicker [minutesGap]="minutesGap" #timepicker></ngx-material-timepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

The above code works perfectly fine in angular 7 but I recently updated to angular 10 and then it has stopped working properly.

In the console the error is :-

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Your minutes - 49 doesn't match your minutesGap - 5
> Error: Your minutes - 49 doesn't match your minutesGap - 5

> core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
> at NgxMaterialTimepickerFaceComponent.increaseClockHand (ngx-material-timepicker.js:1730)
> at NgxMaterialTimepickerFaceComponent.setClockHandPosition (ngx-material-timepicker.js:1686)
> at NgxMaterialTimepickerFaceComponent.ngOnChanges (ngx-material-timepicker.js:1564)
> at  NgxMaterialTimepickerFaceComponent.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:2131)
> at callHook (core.js:3042)
> at callHooks (core.js:3008)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2960)
> at refreshView (core.js:7186)
> at refreshComponent (core.js:8325)
> at refreshChildComponents (core.js:6964)

Comment: check your angular material version

Comment: @angular/material : 10.1.3
@angular/material-moment-adapter : 10.1.3

Answer (score 0):

After Ivy engine (ang 9/10) a lot of libraries also stopped working for me, just clone them into the project and import their module (don't even need to make them as libraries). I think it has to do with view child and a lot of libraries used view child on ngOnIinit instead of the proper way of waiting for the view to render and calling something like ngAfterViewInit. In view engine (ang 8 and before) change detection would run before ngOnInit and viewChild would work not problem, but in ivy they changed this, so a lot of libraries are broken when ngcc command runs to upgrade them.